# Loading localStorage is not updating my variables

Tags: javascript, html, function, local-storage

I got these variables

```
var moneycount = 0;
var b1 = document.createElement("IMG");

function update() {
  document.getElementById('money').innerHTML = moneycount;
}
```

And functions for saving/loading

```
function save() {
  localStorage.setItem("moneycount", moneycount);
};

function load() {
  moneycount = localStorage.getItem("moneycount");
  moneycount = parseInt(moneycount);
  update();
};
```

This function works as intended but wont update with localStorage

```
function add() {
  moneycount = moneycount + 1
  if (moneycount >= 1) {
    document.getElementById('badge1').appendChild(b1);
  }
  update();
}
```

It seems like `var moneycount = 0` still is 0 after I load localStorage because `if (moneycount >= 1)` is not working. The document element is still displaying a bigger number after loading localStorage. Any ideas on how I can store my `add()` function?

Edit:
Found a temporary solution with setting `setInterval(save, 5000);` and adding `<body onload="load();">` and calling it on refresh.

Comment: Your `load()` function does exactly the same thing as `save()`.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to edit when I copy pasted the functions quickly. Fixed now.

Comment: It's still unclear what you're asking. Why would `add()` update localStorage? It doesn't have any code that would do so and it doesn't call `save()`.

Comment: As you see I save and load the variable `moneycount` from localStorage. That is the currency that will display the variable `b1` if `>= 1` but it `= 0` when I load localStorage again.

Comment: Yes, but **where do you call those functions**? Just because the functions exists doesn't mean that they're magically executed whenever the variable's value changes.

Comment: `<div onclick="add()">click</div>` , same with `save()` and `load()`

Answer (score 1):

that is because you do not update the localStorage instead you just update the html element:  should do it as followed:

```
var moneycount = 0;
var b1 = document.createElement("IMG");

    function update() {
      document.getElementById('money').innerHTML = moneycount;
    localStorage.setItem("moneycount", moneycount);

    }



    function save() {
      localStorage.setItem("moneycount", moneycount);
    };





    function add() {
      localStorage.getItem("moneycount")+=  1;
      if (moneycount >= 1) {
        document.getElementById('badge1').appendChild(b1);
      }
      update();
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

The reason is (like mentioned in the comments) that your `load()` function also saves the localStorage instead of retrieving the value.

Your `load()` function should look like this:

```
function load() {
  moneycount = localStorage.getItem("moneycount");
  update();
};
```

Comment: That was my bad when posting the question. I just copy pasted and forgot to edit that part.